# Non-uniform label positioning in legend- contourf Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, contourf

I want to use a bigger scale to show my data!

When I use:

```
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,vmin=6, vmax=9,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
norm= matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=CS.cvalues.min(), vmax=CS.cvalues.max())
```

the legend generated looks fine. (image1) (I know its wrong depiction)

When I use:

```
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,vmin=6, vmax=9,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
norm= matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

The ticks are too congested & only positioned where data is. (image2)

I want image2 with better looking legend. 
I have tried spacing = 'uniform' and spacing = 'proportional' but they dont work.
Any suggestions please!

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Rest of the code:

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap = CS.cmap)
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=CS.levels)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14) 
plt.savefig("aaa.png")
```

Comment: What happens if you use `plt.colorbar(sm)` without setting the ticks at the positions where you don't want to have them?

Comment: It works! thanks a lot..